# Getting error while compiling the program

Tags: solana-program, program, cargo

Hey I am facing this error

```
error[E0658]: let...else statements are unstable
   --> /home/asus/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-1ecc6299db9ec823/solana-frozen-abi-macro-1.16.0/src/lib.rs:422:5
    |
422 | /     let Some(expected_digest) = expected_digest else {
423 | |         return Error::new_spanned(
424 | |             TokenStream2::from(item),
425 | |             "the required \"digest\" = ... attribute is missing.",
...   |
428 | |         .into()
429 | |     };
    | |______^
    |
    = note: see issue #87335 <https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/87335> for more information
    = help: add #![feature(let_else)] to the crate attributes to enable

For more information about this error, try rustc --explain E0658.
error: could not compile solana-frozen-abi-macro due to previous error
warning: build failed, waiting for other jobs to finish...
```

While running to build my program using 'cargo build-bpf'

Comment: I have fixed this error.

Comment: Would you mind putting your solution as an answer to the question? Stackexchange allows you to answer your own question + mark it as the answer. Then if anyone comes across this post in future they'll be able to see how you fixed it :)

Comment: @Pankaj I'm having the same error, would you mind sharing the fix?

Answer (score 6):

This will be fixed if you update your `solana-cli` version.

Update to `1.16.0` by running:

```
solana-install init 1.16.0
```

Comment: Thanks! That fixes it for me!

Comment: Doesn't work for me at either 1.16.0 or 1.16.1